# I need to log the outputs using a button that saves the id of a color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

I have code that produces a clickable box that changes colors from black --> green --> white by cycling through the shades of green whenever the mouse is clicked. I need to integrate code that allows the current selection (whatever shade is currently displayed) to be visible in an output when a button is pressed. So let’s say I click the box 12 times to change the color. I would then hit a button that says "save" for example, and whatever shade is currently displayed in the box would appear in the output. Attached is the code that I have. I need help implementing the button that would allow me to log the button presses so I can see which colors people are selecting. Furthermore, is it possible to save these outputs directly into, say, an excel file? That way they hit the save button and it executes code that directly translates the selected shade into an excel document.

```
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color) + 5;
var c = Math.min(div.dataset.color % 512, 255);
var c2 = Math.max((div.dataset.color % 512) - 255, 0);
div.style.background = 'rgb(' + c2 + ',' + c + ',' + c2 + ')';
})

#myDiv {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #000000;
}

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like:

Color value will be in rgb.

With JS:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor -  will extract the background color
```

With jQuery:

```
jQuery('#myDiv').css("background-color");
```

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color) + 5;
var c = Math.min(div.dataset.color % 512, 255);
var c2 = Math.max((div.dataset.color % 512) - 255, 0);
div.style.background = 'rgb(' + c2 + ',' + c + ',' + c2 + ')';
})

function GetCol()
{
alert(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor);
document.getElementById("ColValue").value = document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor;
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="save and show col" onClick="GetCol()">

<input type="text" id="ColValue">
```

Then after getting the color value use some server side language like php to save this value to excel, db or whatever you want this value to be saved in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getComputedStyle() to get the current style of a element:

Please find an example here

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_getcomputedstyle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the computed background color for the test div.</p>
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button></p>
<div id="test" style="height: 50px;background-color: lightblue;">Test Div</div>
<p>The computed background color for the test div is: <span id="demo"></span></p>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("test");
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getColorOnClick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elem = document.getElementById("mybutton");
  var bgcolor = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

  // do something with bgcolor
}
```